# Do the 3,339 Gods mentioned in Rig Veda III.9.9 indicate number of sages got wisdom before Viswamitra?

Tags: rig-veda, rishi, vishwamitra

Rig Veda [III.9.9](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv03009.htm) says

> trīṇi śatā trī sahasrāṇyaghniṃ triṃśacca devā navacāsaparyan | aukṣan
>   ghṛtairastṛṇan barhirasmā ādid dhotāraṃ nyasādayanta ||
>
> **Three times a hundred Gods and thrice a thousand, and three times ten
>   and nine have worshipped Agni**, For him spread sacred grass, with oil
>   bedewed him, and stablished him as Priest and Sacrificer.

---

This mantra was composed by Sage Viswamitra and dedicated to AGNI.

In this mantra, the sage mentions about ***3,339 Gods***, who worshipped AGNI.

Do the ***3,339 Gods*** mentioned in the mantra indicate that many number of Sages, before him, who got ***WISDOM/BLISS/SELF REALISATION***?

Edit 20-12-19

The another [question and answers](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16693/which-shloka-or-scripture-states-that-there-are-33-crores-of-hindu-gods) thereunder do not answer my question.

Comment: duplicate question.....

Comment: Can you give reference to the original question please? @Swami Vishwananda

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which shloka or scripture states that there are 33 crores of Hindu gods?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16693/which-shloka-or-scripture-states-that-there-are-33-crores-of-hindu-gods)

Comment: Sorry.  That question and answers thereunder do not answer my question please.@Swami Vishwananda