# Can anyone clarify as to why this Rig Vedic mantra mentions Gods differently?

Tags: gods, rig-veda

There was another question on the following topic.  However, my question is different.

[Which shloka or scripture states that there are 33 crores of Hindu gods?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16693/which-shloka-or-scripture-states-that-there-are-33-crores-of-hindu-gods)

---

Rig Veda [III.20.5](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv03020.htm)

> dadahikrāmaghnimuṣasaṃ ca devīṃ bṛhaspatiṃ savitāraṃ cadevam | aśvinā
> mitrāvaruṇā bhaghaṃ ca vasūn rudrānādityāniha huve ||
>
> I call on Savitar the God, on Morning, Bṛhaspati, and Dadhikrās, and
> Agni, On Varuṇa and Mitra, on the Aśvins, Bhaga, the Vasus, Rudras and
> Ādityas.

---

The 33 Gods were [mentioned here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-three_gods), as Vasus, Rudras and Ādityas and 2 Aswins.

---

In Rig Veda IV.1.2 Varuna was mentioned as the brother of AGNI and thus he was an **Aditya**.

> As such, O **Agni**, bring with favour to the Gods **thy Brother Varuṇa** who
> loveth sacrifice, True to the Law, the Āditya who supporteth men, the
> King, supporter of mankind.

---

In the mantra Rig Veda III.20.5, apart from 33 Gods, **Agni,  Varuṇa and Mitra,** who were already included in the list, were mentioned.

Why?

Comment: may because of diferent ststus agni belongs 15th step in devatha latter whereas all other 7 vasus are in 19th step, similarly for varuna and mitra.. mitra is different in taratamya

Comment: @PrasannaR: you can write answer.

Comment: Because in reality, there are 8 Vasus and overlap with 8 of 12 Adityas(mentioned as sons of Aditi in Rig Veda X.72.8) and rulers/guardians of 8 directions or 8 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pahar.  Overlapping 8 Adityas with 8 Vasus are Western Varuna, Mitra, Savitar, Tvastar, Eastern Indra, Bhaga, Aryaman and Martanda https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasu

Answer (score 1):

In the post Vedic literature [Adityas were numbered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%82dityas) as 12.

Rig Veda [X.72.8](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10072.htm) says as follows:

> ***Eight are the Sons of Aditi*** who **from her body sprang to life**. With
> seven she went to meet the Gods she cast Martanda far away.

As per Rig Veda Adityas, sons of aditi, are **only 8 in number**.

Comment: rig veda also mentions 33 devas but it seems the above instance occurred before the birth of other Adityas...