# Do Vedas talk about all the 33 crore deities?

Tags: vedas, gods

Namaste, I have little knowledge about all four Vedas. Personally, I have never got opportunity to read them. I wonder, if all the deities are mentioned in vedas or not. Or, Vedas do **specifically and clearly** talk about only **Shri Vishnu** or only **Shiva** (*not Mahadeva*)?

> Can anybody provide clear picture that do Nigama recognizes all deities?

Comment: This may help https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16693/8735

Comment: @Ketan Thank you! It answers only half of my question. But, I can deal with the answer provided. Actually, I want to know then how do we have so many devi and devatas?