# If Hinduism has only 33 gods made of brahman, then who are the many Graam devtas that we have?

Tags: mantras, brahman, vedic-gods, idols, deity

I have understood that primarily we have 33 gods and these gods are brahman attribute forms of parabrahman But if we go to any tiny village of the country, there will be some graam devta or the village deity. Some deities are installed and some deities are swayambhu. I have seen quite a few people claiming to have experienced the miracles of these devtas. Some even claim to have been possessed by these devtas. Some even go ahead and claim to have seen the deities in human or spiritual form. How is this possible?

Comment: Your understanding is not correct. There are far more than 33 gods

Comment: Sorry you are mistaken. Primarily it is said there are only 33 gods. Search the web please.

Comment: @Carmensandiego There are 33 devatas as listed in the upanishads. Some combination rudras + adityas + maruts, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which shloka or scripture states that there are 33 crores of Hindu gods?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16693/which-shloka-or-scripture-states-that-there-are-33-crores-of-hindu-gods)

Comment: As seen in the link posted by Swami Vishwananda , there are either 33 types or 33 crores. Not 33 devatas @santhosh

Comment: There are only 33 types of Brahman who keep taking forms with different names and clothes as per yuga and region, just like earth is one and same from the age of Rama of Tretayuga to Kaliyuga to today. Anyways Brahman is formless and can take any form and does not look like human in reality which is just an evolved form of ape of Africa. Thats why Hindus worship Ganesha with elephant head and Hanuman monkey and snakes Nagas etc., because Omnipresent God is formless and is present in all natural animals who can evolve, not just humans, an evolved ape species who are currently ruling this earth.

Comment: Is your question specific to graam Devata? Then you may want to clarify that in your question body.

Answer (score 3):

Brahman, Satchidananda, may be thought of as an infinite ocean of Existence, Consciousness and bliss. All the devatas are aspects of this infinite ocean.

> The three main .. deities - the Trinity consisting of Brahma, Visnu
> and Siva - along with their consorts, form the first aspect. Here all
> the .. deities are considered to be different facets of God, the
> Supreme (Isvara). The minor deities like Ganesa and Kumara, form the
> second aspect. Though these deities also are sometimes described as
> the facets of God the Supreme, their position is usually inferior to
> that of the Trinity. They represent limited manifestations of the
> Supreme God. The Lokapalas ( protectors of world), also called as
> Dikpalas (protectors of the cardinal directions) like Indra, Varuna,
> Agni and others, comprise the third aspect. They are actually aspects
> of power in the cosmic scheme of creation and human beings who have
> acquired extraordinary religious merit necessary for getting these
> places, will occupy them in each cycles of creation. **Then there are
> any number of village deities and demigods who can be regarded either
> as very limited manifestations of the Supreme God or as forces of
> nature deified or as human beings who by virtue of some special merit
> and power are elevated to godhood in course of time, after their
> death.**

**Hindu Gods and Goddesses by Swami Harshananda**

**How does one fit in this scheme the 33 gods mentioned in the Vedas?**

> The Rgveda Samhita forms the basic scripture of Hinduism and tradition
> accords it the highest place. The great book is full of hymns, Suktas
> as they are called, which attain supreme heights of poetical beauty
> and philosophical acumen, a rare combination indeed!
>
> A major part of this work is devoted to prayers to gods like Indra,
> Agni, Varuna and others. These Vedic gods are usually enumerated as
> thirty three: eight Vasus, eleven Rudras, twelve Adityas, Indra and
> Prajapati. These gods are assigned to the three regions of the earth
> (Prthvi), the heavens (Dyaus) and the intermediary space (Antariksha).
> ....
>
> Who are these gods? Are they different aspects of the one Supreme God?
> Or, are they different deities competing  and conflicting with one
> another like the Greek gods? Or are they just animals and totems
> masquerading as gods?! .... Suffice it to say that the famous
> statement in the Rgveda itself viz., 'ekam sat viprah bahudha
> vadanti,' 'Truth is one; sages call it by different names' (I.164.46)
> sets the tone for the philosophy of the Vedas which is amplified later
> on by the Upanishads. Hence, though these deities appear to be
> different and independent, they are really facets of the same Brahman,
> the Supreme God.

**Hindu Gods and Goddesses by Swami Harshananda**