# Why are there only 33 devas?

Tags: gods

Why are there only 33 devas in this infinite universe? Are there any more devas other then the 33 named in scripture? And if so how many?

Comment: Check this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16693/26679 We don't even know properly that how many deva species are there. Everyone has different take on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which shloka or scripture states that there are 33 crores of Hindu gods?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16693/which-shloka-or-scripture-states-that-there-are-33-crores-of-hindu-gods)

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda It doesn't answer why there are so few.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Your answer states that the 33 crore devas are manifestations of 33 types of devas. Is there one jiva for each type of deva? If so, why are there so few?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda please dont waste your time on him. This question is already flagged. You can check the conversation in the comments of Answer below and check his profile list of questions.

Comment: @SanatanaDhara You make horrible accusations towards me with no evidence.

Comment: @TerjijKassal please state the accusation so that I can state the evidence. Thank you

Comment: @SanatanaDhara I will not listen to you anymore, every word you have said about me is a lie.

Comment: @TerjijKassal what are you even talking ???? Anyway!!!

Answer (score 1):

There are thousands but are manifestations of 33 Types/aspects of Divinities out of them 11 types are of Rudra, 12 of Aditya (Solar), 8 of Vasus, 1 Indra and 1 Prajapathi. This is what Rishi Yājñavalkya said. But he didn't stop at this point, he continued till he reached ONE and said the one SINGULARITY is  Prana.
About the Infinite state of Brahman:
Yoga/Ramayana of Ṛṣi Vaśiṣṭha says Rudras expand infinitely.
Mahābhārata Itihāsam in its Drona Parva-Nārāyaṇastra-Mokshana Parva 203 says “Infinite Rudras”.
Vājasaneyi Saṃhitā 11th Kanda, 3rd Prayāya, Brahman 1-2 called the  Śatapatha Brahmāṇa which says:

1. Prajāpati is the subtle body of consciousness and upon austerity/Yajñá all Devas arise from his exhaustion. Devas are the phenomenon of ṛta. The final aspect that remains in Prajāpati is the furious essence, this anger is called Manyu (Also described in Rig Veda). It is also explained in the Kṛṣṇa Yajur Veda that the final stage of the fire-altar becomes Rudra, also the remnant of Yajñá becomes whole and so restarts the Yajñá itself. Prajāpati’s tears of anguish and exhaustion which are called Tapodhuma cover the wrath of Manyu. This Manyu is the hundred-headed Rudra with a thousand eyes and thousands of weapons. The remaining three Vedas speak of this multifaceted form of Rudra as Viṣvarūpam, meaning the cosmic form or the all-encompassing omni-form RV 2.33.10/TS 4.5.4/TA 10.23.1. These tears of anguish cover all bhuvanas (lokas) in **countless numbers**, and they are all called Rudras. Since this form originated from anguish/cry (ruditāt), He is called Rudra. So, the word Rudra has many meanings based on the process involved, this is why Rudra is the Divinity of many contradictions and so becomes a natural epithet to all Vedic Divinities. This incomprehensible fierce form frightened all the Devas, so they asked Prajāpati to pacify him. They gathered calming oblations/offerings called Śāntadevatyam; this calming oblation to Rudra is called Śāntarudriya.
2. How can one offer oblations to the Lord who encompasses all? What can one offer to Him that is not His? These Svāhākāra (oblations) in the form of Gaveduka were offered in the Northern region of the Agnihotram (fire-altar) because this is the region of Rudra (hence the title dakṣiṇin marutāṃ) RV5.60, and so a Gaveduka plant grew at that palace, and Prajāpati said: **“we satisficed him with his own share with his own essence”**. Similarly, leaves of Arka were offered and an Arka plant grew at that place and again Prajāpati said “we satisfice him with his own share with his own essence”.
3. Svāhākāras offered from the height of the knees are received by Rudras encompassing Earth and below realms; similarly, oblations given from the navel region are received by all Rudras of the aerial region called antariksha; then oblations given from the mouth region are received by those from the upper celestial regions. Finally, the oblation is surrendered to the hundred-headed manifestation of Rudra; this form is titled Kṣatra, meaning the chief/head/owner. From the tears of Kṣatra came Viś, and Viś became Creation itself and its beings, they became people or commoners. These Viś gave the first oblations/anuvākam of Śataśirsarudra to Ekadevataya (the One Divinity), who is Kṣatra. This very concept gave way to Eka-Vrātya or Eko-He-Rudra, meaning **“there is none that is not Rudra”**. And Viś became the root word for Viśvam, and if we go to Kṛṣṇa Yajur Veda Taittirīya Saṃhitā 4.5.5 says “नमो गिरिशाय च शिपिविष्टाय च” meaning salutations to the one who resides on the mountains and who becomes Viśvam (ŚipiViṣṭa). Please note that ŚipiViṣṭa is a title given to Viśnu as well, as Viśnu is the personification of Viśvam. Hence Prajāpati says **“we satisficed him with his own share with his own essence”** and this conclusion corresponds with Kṛṣṇa Yajur Veda Taittirīya Saṃhitā1.8.6 which in return landed in both Svetasvatara Upaniṣhad and Chandogya Upaniṣhad (two among the 18 primary Upaniṣhad).

> There is (हि) The One (एको ) Rudrā (रुद्रो) and none (न) other than
> He, none can make Him second (द्विती) in being (याय), that is in
> existence (तस्थु:र्य) among worlds( इमां:ल्लोका), He is the authority
> (ईशते) by His own authority (ईशनीभिः)| In all worlds/celestial
> dimensions (भुवनानि), is His projection and under His guardians
> (संसृज् + ज्य + गोपाः) in entirety (विश्वा), He is established
> (तिष्ठति) in all beings (हे जनाः) as the indweller (प्रत्यङ्); and all
> beings (भूत्वा), at the time of final dissolution (अन्त:काले),
> become/withdraw into Him (सञ्चुकोच) ~ Svetasvatara Upaniṣhad 3.2
>
> सदेव सोम्येदमग्र आसीदेकमेवाद्वितीयम् । तद्धैक आहुरसदेवेदमग्र
> आसीदेकमेवाद्वितीयं तस्मादसतः सज्जायत ॥6.2.1 कुतस्तु खलु
> सोम्यैवंस्यादिति होवाच कथमसतः सज्जायेतेति। सत्त्वेव सोम्येदमग्र
> आसीदेकमेवाद्वितीयम् ॥ 6.2.2 यथा सोम्य मधु मधुकृतो निस्तिष्ठन्ति
> नानात्ययानां वृक्षाणांरसान्समवहारमेकतांरसं गमयन्ति ॥ 6.9.1 ते यथा तत्र
> न विवेकं लभन्तेऽमुष्याहं वृक्षस्य रसोऽस्म्यमुष्याहं वृक्षस्य
> रसोऽस्मीत्येवमेव खलु सोम्येमाः सर्वाः प्रजाः सति सम्पद्य न विदुः सति
> सम्पद्यामह इति ॥ “from a single ball of clay, we can know every form
> made of clay, the difference in form is but the name (nama-rūpa). In
> the beginning was one being, without a second, or non-being, without a
> second; and from that various beings came to be. Just like bees make
> one honey from nectars of various flowers, yet the honey do not know
> from which tree or flower, in the same way, all beings begotten from
> One Being do not know their source” Please note: the word “Being”
> doesn’t mean a person nor an alien or animal, beings means “to be” or
> “to exist”. Existence can’t be described or iconified with in
> image/form within the frontier of vocabulary.
> ~Chandogya Upaniṣhad 6.2.1/6.2.2/6.9.1/6.9.2

Sources: [SataRudriya](http://namahshivaya.net/the-pinnacle-of-rudra-sri-rudram-rudra-prashna-satarudriya/) [Counting Rudras](http://namahshivaya.net/how-many-rudras/) [Raw Unmanifest Rudra](http://namahshivaya.net/rudra-the-un-manifested-raw-that-which-is-not/)

Comment: @TerjijKassal I am not certain as to what's in your mind. Jiva = a force/vibration/energy that holds the subtle body and gross body together using Vayu (Air that gets split into 5). So there is no necessity for DEVA to be tethered to a physical body. Vedic Devas are Cosmic Phenomino. 33 are their classification. Let's take a tornado, nothing but Air + Heat, both are cosmic phenomena. The air closer to land gets warm and the air higher in attitude is cold. Warm air wants to raise, and cold air wants to push down. When they meet, physical entities on the ground together become a tornado.

Comment: @TerjijKassal What I am saying is, there is no need for a cosmic phenomenon to have a jiva. There are many puranic incidents where Rishis give them Kshrap, eg. Lord Brahma bestows Kshrap on Ganga to take a physical form. So they may and may not. Second, jiva is not a singular entity, a human being is a constitution of millions of microorganisms, without them, we will die in a matter of hours. So are we to say each organism doesn't have a jiva? Or that we as a human are only a single Jiva. No. Rishi Vasista says "Jiva fell on this planet like rain".. everything and anything is jiva. Cont...

Comment: @TerjijKassal Cont 2 .. of the above comment.
So, please don't read about Jiva on Wikipedia. You have to look at Jiva across the spectrum of literature to understand how they used this term and its context. Some people use the composite term called Jivatma which means Jiva's Atman. Gita uses it as the witnessing entity that carries memory from one form to another. So can Vedic Rudra and Vishnu and Prajapathi have Jivas? We can't just fix that as a constant, as they are entities/concepts that exist before creation. Jiva = Shakti. Atman = Cit.  Here is a link http://sanatanadhara.com/rebirth/

Comment: @TerjijKassal Cont 3 .. of the above comment.
This is the reason why I gave the Vedic evolution of creation and compared it with a primary Upanishad.

Comment: @TerjijKassal Two words ... cosmic phenomenon and ex of Ganga. you seem to be trying to equate Sanatana Culture Devas same as Biblical angels.

Comment: @TerjijKassal unless there is a new Question not covered above, there is no reason for further discussion. Having said that, the example above shows that a cosmic phenomenon can on various occasions take up a physical manifestation like Heat and Air together to become a tornado. After providing a Vedic answer, this discussion reminds me of a commonality in many, which is the fear of the unknown and uncertain, that makes human emotion see security, esp in a Deva or Divine aspect who can hear/see our change and so reward us/save us/protect us. So, Shape/form is a prominent solace that many seek.

Comment: @TerjijKassal I feel the way you're commenting, doesn't look like you have intention of learning things about Hinduism. If you're here for making fun of Devi devata, then I suggest you do it elsewhere. Consider this as warning.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto he is not sincere, He is just wasting time with redundant questions (if you check his profile). Just an ignoramus bot. Please downvote the question and ask it to be closed.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Why do you feel this way? In fact I am not making fun of Devi devata, I am going against those who attribute absurd weaknesses to the devas.

Comment: @TerjijKassal Then why is [this comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53884/why-are-there-only-33-devas/53885?noredirect=1#comment167277_53885) ??

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto this TerjijKassal person is either too smart or he is an ignoramus. There is a clear description above in my comments regarding Jiva and its association with Devas and the various paradigms it can understand with examples. He is trying to build up content on the stack exchange site. Kindly downvote the question and request for closing. Very soon you will see another similar question popping up. He is not ready to do any exploration of himself.

Comment: @SanatanaDhara I am merely going against those who do not understand that the devas are far beyond humans.

Comment: @TerjijKassal first, you say "going against those who do not understand that the devas are far beyond" then you say "just confused". How can a confused person go against those who do not understand? Finally tornado was an analogy, we both know that and you are not that dumb. I also gave an example of Ganga who is a Devi yet attained a human form and gave birth to Bhisma. I am writing this comment so that others who read this conversation will know. Here is the URL pointing to Terjij's questions, see the pattern https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/28803/terjij-kassal

Comment: @SanatanaDhara Why are you a liar? You should be ashamed of yourself.

Comment: @TerjijKassal please share as which part of my statements is a lie? In fact its you who said "Sanatana Dhara said that devas don't have jivas, and compared them to tornados". We both know that is not what I said, and we both know what an analogy means and denotes. We both know the tornedo was an analogy. Nice try!!!!

Comment: @SanatanaDhara Also, why did you mention Abrahamic angels?